# extract the first three word in a string out

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have the following codes:

```
        void dbSvc_retrievepopularhawkerCompleted(object sender, RouteServiceRef.retrievepopularhawkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<RouteServiceRef.Hawker> recommendPlaceList;
        recommendPlaceList = e.Result.Cast<RouteServiceRef.Hawker>().ToList();

        string hawkername = "";
        string address = "";
        string postal = "";
        double coordX = 0.0;
        double coordY = 0.0;
        double popularity = 0;



        foreach (RouteServiceRef.Hawker rp in recommendPlaceList)
        {
            hawkername = rp.hawkername;
            address = rp.address;
            postal = rp.postal;
            coordX = rp.xcoord;
            coordY = rp.ycoord;
            popularity = rp.popularity;

            cities.Add(new City() { Name = hawkername, Population = popularity });



        }


        ColumnSeries bs = ChartControl.Series[0] as ColumnSeries; bs.ItemsSource = cities;



    }
```

How can I extract the first three word in the string of the hawkername ? The result for hawkername is:

[image]

**I need to get the first three string out.**

Comment: Do you need the first three words in each string, or the first three items in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var firstThreeWords = hawkername.Split(' ').Take(3);
```

Don't forget to include `using System.Linq;` if you're not already using it:

Comment: Take returns an IEnumerable. If you want to use it as string again, use: `string.Join(" ", hawkername.Split(' ').Take(3));`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do :

```
var input = "ldsk bkfd badk klsfdl";
var result = string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Take(3));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```